# How to access atomia DNS web app over public IP?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system

After installing everything and trying to access Atomia DNS's web app over public IP/port, I get "This webpage is not available".  In the guide they access the web app over `http://localhost:5380` but I need to access it over my VPS's public IP address. 
OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

To add one thing I found. Seems like web app crashes right away, that's why it's not working

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /usr/lib/atomiadns/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/utils.js:38:10
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/atomiadns/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:452:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/atomiadns/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:7:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
```

Guess this is more for stackoverflow then?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and debugged - this occurs cause Atomia's webapp installed a version of the Node.js "express" module which is too new.

I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04 here and it comes with node.js 0.6.x - the express module version that Atomia installs for the webapp requires node.js 0.8.x though.

The best way I found to fix this is to downgrade the express module which I did like this:

aptitude update
aptitude -y install npm
cd /usr/lib/atomiadns/webapp/node_modules/
mv express express.backup
npm install express@3.2.2

(3.2.2 seems to be the latest version that supports node.js 0.6.x).

After that, the webapp went back to working fine. Hope this helps! :-)

Cheers,
Chris

Edit: I just came across two other errors which are caused by a too new version of the jade and request modules, to fix do this, after the commands above:

cd /usr/lib/atomiadns/webapp/node_modules/
mv jade jade.backup
mv request request.backup
npm install jade@0.27.7
npm install request@2.9.100